# Data sources for Alexa and Compete rankings

Tags: traffic, analytics, alexa

How do Alexa and Compete get their data?  which one is better?

Answer (score 2):

**From Alexa:**

> Gathering Web Usage Information
>   In addition to the Alexa Crawl, which
>   can tell us what is on the Web, Alexa
>   utilizes web usage information, which
>   tells us what is being seen on the
>   web. This information comes from the
>   community of Alexa Toolbar users. Each
>   member of the community, in addition
>   to getting a useful tool, is giving
>   back. Simply by using the toolbar each
>   member contributes valuable
>   information about the web, how it is
>   used, what is important and what is
>   not. This information is returned to
>   the community with improved Related
>   Links, Traffic Rankings and more.

**From Compete:**

> Compete’s clickstream data are
>   collected from a 2,000,000 member
>   panel of US Internet users (about a 1%
>   sample), using diverse sources. Using
>   a rigorous statistical normalization
>   methodology, Compete creates precise
>   projections of the behavior of the
>   entire US Internet browser population
>   on monthly and weekly basis. In
>   addition, Compete provides daily
>   estimates of share of consumer
>   attention garnered by the top Internet
>   sites and the velocity of change of
>   this attention. Compete is the only
>   commercial web analytics provider to
>   make its data freely available online
>   for all Internet users.

From my own experience, I think Alexa is more reliable, because its user database is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really that easy to compare, because they deal in different metrics.

Looking at Compete's Unique Visitors for a site that i'm involved in, they give an average of 4,000 unique visitors per month. Google Analytics for the site average 180,000 unique visitors per month.

For Alexa, the metrics are all expressed as a percentage of global stats, or "
unique pages per day" -- things that no one else uses, so there's no way to gauge the accuracy of the stats.

However, i believe that the problem is the small, US-centric sample which penalises non-US sites (FYI, the site i'm talking about here is for a business in South East Asia).

Moreover, looking at the textual information that Alexa presents, i'm concerned that it's several years out of date, which makes me doubt the efficiency of the system. According to Wikipedia:

> On November 27, 2008, Amazon announced that Alexa Web Search was no longer accepting new customers, and the service would be deprecated or discontinued for existing customers on January 26, 2009

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexa_Internet) is a good read, as it talks about the accuracy of stats.

Final word: trust only verified stats!

Comment: yes, for Alexa, the metrics are all expressed as a percentage of global stats. Still, it is possible to get estimation based on these data. i.e. http://www.rank2traffic.com/, http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm