# how is sites such as alexa.com monitor all web wide sites traffic in the internet ?

Tags: monitoring, traffic, alexa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [alexa and compete](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6602/alexa-and-compete)

Hello,

i'm trying to understand idea of traffic monitoring sites such as alexa.com , which can monitor traffic for any site in the internet (although if it not registered account underit and didn't put any code to alexa for help it to monitor this site traffic) ??

Comment: Just like TV show rating companies do - take a sample and multiply it up.

Answer (score 2):

They gather their data through users who install the Alexa Tool Bar.  See their [Company](http://www.alexa.com/company) page for details.